# Automatically registering "commands" for a command line program in python

Tags: python, command-line-tool

I would like to develop a command-line program that can process and give "help" for subcommands.  To be concrete, say I have a single script called "cgent" and I would like to have subcommands "abc", "def", and "xyz" execute and accept the rest of the sys.args for processing by optparse.

```
cgent abc [options] 
cgent help abc
....
```

All of this is straightforward if I hard-code the subcommand names.  However, I would like to be able to continue to add subcommands by adding a class or module (?).  This is similar to the idea that is used by web frameworks for adding controllers, for example.  I have tried digging through pylons to see if I can recreate what is done there, but I have not unravelled the logic.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to create a "command registry". This can be as simple as a dictionary.

In the main program you do:

```
commands = {}
```

And in any submodules you add you do

```
from yourmodule.main import commands

def mynewcommand(arguments=here):
    pass

commands['newcommand'] = mynewcommand
```

Then you can use argparse to handle the commands. In which case your module needs to add the subparser part for the command too.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have to do complex parsing of arguments I recommend the [baker](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Baker) module. It lets you define subcommands and their arguments through decorators. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import baker

@baker.command()
def foo(a=1):
    print 'foo:', a

@baker.command()
def baz(b=1):
    print 'baz:', b

baker.run()
```

defines the two subcommands `foo` and `baz`, with (optional) parameters `a` and `b`.
So you can use them like this:

```
$ ./test_baker.py foo --a 2
foo: 2
$ ./test_baker.py baz
baz: 1
```

It also uses the docstrings to generate the help.

Since the `baker` module is global, your subcommands can span several `.py` files. As long as they are imported, the subcommands will be automatically registered.

Moreover it is just a single `.py` file so you can just drop it in your source tree.